# Why is CG Image not being released?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-graphics

I've been banging my head for some time on a larger project with a memory leak. I've managed to create a very basic CLI app that duplicates the issue.

Why is CG Image not being released?

[image]

The real app would actually create a bunch of thumbs of various sizes. This just demo just uses the same size over and over again.

This is compiled without ARC.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString * image = @"/Users/sean/Pictures/wallpaper/7gjMT.jpg";
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:image];

        CFDataRef imgData = (CFDataRef)imageData;
        CGImageRef imgRef;
        CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = NULL;
        imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imgData);
        imgRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        CGDataProviderRelease(imgDataProvider);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            // create context, keeping original image properties
            CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imgRef);

            CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 2560, 1440,
                                            CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imgRef),
                                            CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imgRef),
                                            colorspace,
                                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

            // draw image to context (resizing it)
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 2560, 1440), imgRef);

            // extract resulting image from context
            CGImageRef newImgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

            CGImageRelease(imgRef);
            imgRef = newImgRef;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. context is never released. Add `CGContextRelease(context);` to your for loop
2. you probably want to add content inside `for` loop into `@autoreleaspool{}`

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

  @autoreleaspool { 
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imgRef);

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 2560, 1440,
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imgRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imgRef),
                                        colorspace,
                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

        // draw image to context (resizing it)
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 2560, 1440), imgRef);

        // extract resulting image from context
        CGImageRef newImgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        CGImageRelease(imgRef);
        CGContextRelease(context);

        imgRef = newImgRef;
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, you are so right. I actually have that in the main project I copied this code from, it got missed somehow when I condensed it down. While you helped me fix this little test loop, the main project is still having the same issue which means it's elsewhere. Thanks again.